# A mysterious geometric argument regarding mollification in Evans's PDE book

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following argument is made in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations*, Chapter 5.3.3:

> [image]
>   [image]

Here are my **questions**:

> - As I can read from the argument, $\lambda\varepsilon$ would be eventually small enough if $\varepsilon>0$ is small enough. Why on earth would one need $\lambda$ to be sufficiently large? What if we just define 
>     $$
>   x^\varepsilon=x+\varepsilon e_n?
>   $$
> - What does "there is room to mollify within $U$" mean? How does one know
>     $$
>   v^\varepsilon\in C(\overline{V})?
>   $$

Comment: $u\in C^\infty(U)$ such that all the partial derivatives  of $u$ has continuous extension to $\partial U$.

Comment: Ok then I don't get why we don't consider $u_n = u \ast \eta_{1/n}$ (or $(u \ast \eta_{1/n})1_{u \in \overline{U}}$) directly ?

Comment: Well anyway, in general the $C^\infty$ approximation is $u_n(x) = u \ast \eta_{1/n}(f_n(x))$ or $u_n = u(g_n(x)) \ast \eta_{1/n}(x)$ where $f_n(x),g_n(x) \to x$ are some smooth deformation of $U$ and $\eta_{1/n}(x)$ is a sequence of mollifiers. Beside that, the details aren't very interesting.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is too small, then for $x$ near the boundary of $U$ the ball $B(x^\epsilon,\epsilon)$ could protrude from $U$. My intuition is that the necessary $\lambda$ would be determined by the gradient of $\gamma$ near $x_0$.

Comment: I would be very interested in seeing an example showing how the case $\lambda=1$ could fail.

Comment: Draw some pictures! If you start with a rapidly oscillating boundary $\gamma$ then you should be able to cook up an example pretty easily.